# Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function in Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get fullcalendar to render data from my db, when something is dropped. I can see the data is passed correctly by ajax. But when the callback is called, I get the error message ***Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function***.

Below you find my code:

```
   drop: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var resource_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var id = resource_id.substring(resource_id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, resource_id.length);
        var events_uri = '/get_resource_events';
        $.ajax({
            url: resource_base_url() + events_uri,
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var events = [];
                for (order in data) {
                    var allday_data = data[order].allday;
                    if (allday_data === 'true') {
                        allday_data = true;
                    } else {
                        allday_data = false;
                    };
                    events.push({
                        id: data[order].id,
                        title: [data[order].initials] + [data[order].last_name],
                        start: data[order].start,
                        end: data[order].end,
                        allDay: allday_data,
                        color: data[order].calendar_color
                    });
                };
                callback(events);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
            }
        });
    }
```

Anyone any sugestions to solve the error message?

below the results from ajax, to callback

```
[{"id":"136","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-05 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-05 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"138","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-04 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-04 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"139","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-07 07:30:00","end":"2014-08-07 11:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"142","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-06 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"143","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-06 11:30:00","end":"2014-08-06 15:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"155","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-10 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-10 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"170","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-28 10:00:00","end":"2014-08-28 15:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"171","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-26 08:00:00","end":"2014-08-26 12:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"175","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-30 07:00:00","end":"2014-08-30 14:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"183","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-29 07:30:00","end":"2014-08-29 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"}]
```

I tried the solution you described, but I still get the same error message ***object is not a function***. Below you find the compleat JS file. Anyone any other suggestions?

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

function resource_base_url() {
    return base_url() + '/resource_controller/';
}

/* initialize the calendar
-----------------------------------------------------------------*/
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    firstDay: 1, // Sunday=0, Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.
    aspectRatio: 2.5,
    eventTextColor: 'black',
    theme: true, // false, true
    handleWindowResize: true,
    editable: true,
    droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            // Determines which icons are displayed in buttons of the header when theming is on.
    themeButtonIcons:{ // Check http://api.jqueryui.com/theming/icons/ for avalible icon names
        prev: 'ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-w',
        next: 'ui-icon ui-icon-circle-triangle-e'
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },       
    //events: calendar_base_url() + '/events',        
    eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
        if (event.allDay === 'true') {
            event.allDay = true;
        } else {
            event.allDay = false;
        }
    },
    drop: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var resource_id = $(this).attr('id');
        var id = resource_id.substring(resource_id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, resource_id.length);
        var events_uri = '/get_resource_events';
        $.ajax({
            url: resource_base_url() + events_uri,
            data: {
                id: id
            },
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val){
                    var events = [];
                    var allday_data = val.allday;
                    if (allday_data === 'true') {
                        allday_data = true;
                    } else {
                        allday_data = false;
                    };
                    events.push({
                        id: val.id,
                        title: val.initials + val.last_name,
                        start: val.start,
                        end: val.end,
                        allDay: allday_data,
                        color: val.calendar_color
                    });
                callback(events);
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
                });
            }
        });
    }    
});
```

});

Comment: Can we see your callback?

Comment: You should declare "order" in the success callback with `var`.

Comment: Also that "title" attribute - you're adding together two arrays? What is the point of that?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to do the loop trough json Object, try to do this like this with each function.
hope it help's

You must put event in global scope of window like this

```
      <script> 
        var events = new Array();
      </script>
```

And all your functions in document ready function.

```
 drop: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    var resource_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = resource_id.substring(resource_id.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, resource_id.length);
    var events_uri = '/get_resource_events';
    $.ajax({
        url: resource_base_url() + events_uri,
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        type: "GET",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
               var events = [];

                   var allday_data = val.allday;
                   if (allday_data === 'true') {
                       allday_data = true;
                   } else {
                       allday_data = false;
                   };
                   events.push({
                       id: val.id,
                       title: val.initials + val.last_name,
                       start: val.start,
                       end: val.end,
                      allDay: allday_data,
                      color: val.calendar_color

                  });

              callback(events);
              $('#calendar').fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
             )}
          }
    });
}
```

Here is working example :

```
var events = new Array();
$(document).ready(function(){

        var data = [{"id":"136","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-05 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-05 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"138","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-04 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-04 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"139","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-07 07:30:00","end":"2014-08-07 11:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"142","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-06 00:00:00","end":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"143","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-06 11:30:00","end":"2014-08-06 15:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"155","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-10 09:00:00","end":"2014-08-10 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"170","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-28 10:00:00","end":"2014-08-28 15:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"171","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-26 08:00:00","end":"2014-08-26 12:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"175","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-30 07:00:00","end":"2014-08-30 14:30:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"},{"id":"183","initials":"M.H.","last_name":"Tjon-Sien-Fat","start":"2014-08-29 07:30:00","end":"2014-08-29 13:00:00","allday":null,"calendar_color":"#00ffff"}];

 $.each(data, function(key, val){


               var allday_data = val.allday;
               if (allday_data === 'true') {
                   allday_data = true;
               } else {
                   allday_data = false;
               };

               events.push({
                   id: val.id,
                   title: [val.initials] + [val.last_name],
                   start: val.start,
                   end: val.end,
                   allDay: allday_data,
                   color: val.calendar_color

              });

            })

      console.log(events);
   });
```

Here is the output

```
  [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

  Object0: ObjectallDay: falsecolor: "#00ffff", end: "2014-08-05 13:00:00", id: "136", start: "2014-08-05 09:00:00", title: "M.H.Tjon-Sien-Fat";
```